Uso del verbo essere, tra l’inglese e l’italiano
Qual è la differenza della funzione del verbo essere tra:

quello sei tu
quello è sbagliato

ad esempio nella prima frase il soggetto sembra essere “tu”, a cui si riferisce il verbo “sei”, coniugato quindi alla seconda persona singolare.
nella seconda frase invece, il soggetto sembra essere il pronome.
Allora perché anche nel primo caso “quello” non è il soggetto? Gli inglesi direbbero, ad esempio: “All I want is you”, per cui il verbo essere si riferisce al soggetto (con la terza persona) “All”. In italiano diremmo: “Quello che voglio sei tu”, col verbo in seconda persona.

Scusa, non mi è del tutto chiaro che cosa stai chiedendo. Inglese e italiano sono ovviamente lingue diverse, con costruzioni grammaticali diverse, ma la tua domanda qual è?

Entrambe le frasi sono costituite da un soggetto e da un predicato nominale. La funzione del verbo essere all'interno del predicato nominale viene detta "copula":

A (soggetto) + verbo essere (copula) + B

Tu è un pronome personale soggetto, questo significa che svolge sempre funzione di soggetto all'interno della frase. Il verbo, dunque, viene coniugato alla seconda persona singolare:

Quello (B) + sei (copula) + tu (soggetto)

Quando il pronome personale "tu" non svolge la funzione di soggetto, si trova  nelle forme "te" o "ti". Nel caso del predicato nominale si usa "te":

Io non sono te.
Io (soggetto) + non sono (copula) + te (B)

Una frase come:

Quello non è te.

è teoricamente corretta, tuttavia suona male e altri costrutti sono più naturali (es. "Quello non è come te." o "Lui non è te.").
Nel secondo caso sbagliato è un aggettivo, dunque non può svolgere la funzione di soggetto, a meno che non venga "sostantivato" (es. "I belli spesso sono vanitosi."). Dunque il pronome quello è sicuramente il soggetto e il verbo viene coniugato alla terza persona singolare.
In conclusione la funzione del verbo essere è sempre la stessa, è la copula di un predicato nominale.
